# How to use RandomizedSearchCV of Scikit-Learn with ImageDataGenerator of Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I'm trying to implement a RandomizedSearchCV using the ImageDataGenerators.

Here an example of the generator used for the train set:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20,
                                        rescale=1./255,
                                        shear_range=0.2,
                                        zoom_range=0.25,
                                        horizontal_flip=True,
                                        width_shift_range=0.2,
                                        height_shift_range=0.2)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(paths["train_path"],
                                                batch_size=train_batch_size,
                                                class_mode='binary',
                                                target_size=(image_shape[0], image_shape[1]))
```

I've done the same for the `validation_generator` and finally the model has been fitted as:

```
model_history = model.fit(train_generator, 
                        epochs=200, 
                        steps_per_epoch=train_steps_per_epoch,
                        validation_data=validation_generator, 
                        validation_steps=valdation_steps_per_epoch,
                        callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=20)])
```

I would like to apply a grid search (using sklearn RandomizedSearchCV) to optimize my model, for that reason I used SciKeras:

```
rnd_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_reg, param_distribs, n_iter=10, cv=3)
```

where `keras_reg` is the `KerasClassifier` which wraps the model for sklearn and `param_distribs` is the dictionary with the hyperparameters values.

Finally I fitted the RandomizedSearchCV object as follows:

```
rnd_search_cv.fit(train_generator, 
                epochs=200, 
                steps_per_epoch=train_steps_per_epoch,
                validation_data=validation_generator, 
                validation_steps=valdation_steps_per_epoch,
                callbacks=[callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=20)])
```

I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/docker_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 684, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Do you know how to integrate RandomizedSearchCV and ImageDataGenerator objects?

Comment: Does not seem like sciKeras supports training with generators. You can use KerasTuner which does support generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I don't recommend the below solution and approch.** I highly recommend using [`KerasTuner`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/keras_tuner) but If you want to input [`keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/DirectoryIterator) like your `train_generator` to [`RandomizedSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) you need to extract `X` and `Y` from `DirectoryIterator` then input them to RandomizedSearchCV like below:

```
import numpy  as np

len_dataset = 100
batch_size = 32
image_size = (150,150)
channel_images = 3
num_clases = 5
x_train = np.empty((len_dataset*batch_size, 
              image_size[0], 
              image_size[1], 
              channel_images))
y_train = np.empty((len_dataset*batch_size, num_clases))

for idx in range(len_dataset):
    x_batch, y_batch = train_generator.__getitem__(idx)
    for i in range(x_batch.shape[0]):
        x_train[idx*batch_size+i] = x_batch[i]
        y_train[idx*batch_size+i] = y_batch[i]

rnd_search_cv.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Yup SciKeras is a compatibility layer with Scikit-Learn. There are no data generators in Scikit-Learn and so SciKeras does not support them as inputs. You could hack something together using transformers, but I would encourage you to stick to Keras native tools at that point.